# Change Windows XP lock screen background

Tags: windows-xp

I need to change the background image when a user has locked the system.   Currently, it displays the users desktop, but it has become a security issue (not sure how, but it has).

So now - I need to change the background image to a blank (black image with legal text) whenever the user has locked their system (ctrl-alt-del lock workstation).

I have changed the registry located at

HKEY_USERS.DEFAULT\Control Panel\Desktop\Wallpaper

This works for the initial login screen, but what i am looking for is how to change the background on the lock screen.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I was able to do wallpaper change via power shell.
(I guess it powershell 2 - "host" returns "2.0")
It might get you (or someone else) started.
(pieces found on (Hey, Scripting Guy!) etc - I never used powershell before)

Program should create object

```
$sysevent = [microsoft.win32.systemevents]
```

create function that will cahnge wallpaper
It is called on lock and on unlock - your should research how to tell a difference. I just check which BMP I have and change it to another one

```
Function Global:OnLock{
$wp=Get-ItemProperty -path 'HKCU:\Control Panel\Desktop\' -name wallpaper
Write-Host "Current WP:" $wp.WallPaper
if ($wp.WallPaper -eq "C:\Documents and Settings\username\Local Settings\Application Data\Microsoft\Wallpaper2.bmp")
{Set-ItemProperty -path 'HKCU:\Control Panel\Desktop\' -name wallpaper -value "C:\Documents and Settings\username\Local Settings\Application Data\Microsoft\Wallpaper1.bmp"}
else
{Set-ItemProperty -path 'HKCU:\Control Panel\Desktop\' -name wallpaper -value "C:\Documents and Settings\username\Local Settings\Application Data\Microsoft\Wallpaper2.bmp"}
rundll32.exe user32.dll, UpdatePerUserSystemParameters
}
```

register event

```
Register-ObjectEvent -InputObject $sysevent -EventName "SessionSwitch" -Action {OnLock} -SourceIdentifier "ExecuteOnLock"
```

Now, lock/unlock will call that function.
Of cource (?) you have to leave powershell running
For example by

```
powershell -NoExit -WindowStyle Hidden C:\pathToPrScript\script.ps1
```

Hope that helps